# Windows service access folder under project

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, export, directory

I am trying to work on a service where I need to export a report into a folder under the service project and email it to the user.  The delete the report when complete.  The issue I am having is I need to know how to access a folder under the project.   I know you can use System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to get into the bin where the excuting file is but I want to get to a folder is this possible? If not is there a way of creating the folder under the bin directory and accessing it. I can manually create a folder under the bin but didnt really want to do that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I know you can use System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory to get into the bin where the excuting file is but I want to get to a folder is this possible?` What does this mean? How do you think a "bin" is different from a "folder"?

Comment: I know a bin directory is a folder but didn't want to put my working folders under the bin.  I ended up doing that and just adding the folder to the install package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Application path, better option for temp files is Temp directory or AppData directory. You may not get write access to the installed directory.